# odoo Rml Barcode custom function call inside tag

Tags: python, odoo, barcode, odoo-8

I have a *rml* file which is used to generate *barcode* in my program.
In that *rml* file:

```
<barCode code='EAN13' >[[data['something'] or '']]</barCode>
```

is the line that generates *barcode* for my file which specifies that the *barcode* to be generated must be an *ean13* format.

However I would like to specify the code based on my values I have tried to use something like:

```
<barCode code='get_code()' >[[data['ean13'] or '']]</barCode>
```

Where my:

```
def get_code(self, ean):
        if something.something=='some':
            return 'EAN13'
        else:
            return 'Code128'
```

However it is not working for some reason.

How can I use an `if` Condition **inside** a tag in a *rml*?

Comment: An `if`loop ? `if` isn't a loop.

Comment: sorry for that i meant an if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i ended up creating 2 seperate rml files and giving call to those files based upon what value i requird if i wanted to egenerate a ean13 barcode i would call file with

```
<barCode code='EAN13' >[[data]]</barCode>
```

and if type 128 i would call an entirly diffrent rml file

```
<barCode code='Code128' >[[data']]</barCode>
```